# Python doesn't write back to file modified line

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-io

I have this function that is supposed to modify an int in the format of a string and write back the changes to the file. I am sure the isbn passed to the function is correct.

Here is my function:

```py
def decrementBookUnits(isbn):
    with open('books.txt', 'r') as booksFile:
        content = booksFile.readlines()
        for line in content:
            if str(isbn) in line:
                wordList = line.split(' -- ')
                wordList2 = wordList[6].split(':')
                if int(wordList2[1]) == isbn:
                    wordList3 = wordList[5].split(':')
                    wordList[1] = wordList3[1].replace('3', '666')
                    with open('books.txt', 'w') as booksFile:
                        booksFile.writelines(content)
```

And here is what the books.txt file looks like for context:

```
    ID:0 -- Title:ff -- Author:dfdf -- Editor:df -- YearOfRelease:2000 -- NumberOfUnits:3 -- ISBN:123
    ID:01 -- Title:title -- Author:author -- Editor:editor -- YearOfRelease:2003 -- NumberOfUnits:1 -- ISBN:1234
    ID:03 -- Title:title -- Author:author -- Editor:editor -- YearOfRelease:2000 -- NumberOfUnits:0 -- ISBN:321
    ID:04 -- Title:title -- Author:author -- Editor:editor -- YearOfRelease:2000 -- NumberOfUnits:4 -- ISBN:44
    ID:05 -- Title:title -- Author:author -- Editor:editor -- YearOfRelease:20055 -- NumberOfUnits:3 -- ISBN:33
    ID:06 -- Title:title -- Author:author -- Editor:editor -- YearOfRelease:2006 -- NumberOfUnits:6 -- ISBN:70
    ID:07 -- Title:title -- Author:author -- Editor:editor -- YearOfRelease:2011 -- NumberOfUnits:7 -- ISBN:54
    ID:08 -- Title:title -- Author:author -- Editor:editor -- YearOfRelease:2000 -- NumberOfUnits:4 -- ISBN:44
    ID:09 -- Title:title -- Author:author -- Editor:editor -- YearOfRelease:20055 -- NumberOfUnits:3 -- ISBN:33
    ID:10 -- Title:title -- Author:author -- Editor:editor -- YearOfRelease:2006 -- NumberOfUnits:6 -- ISBN:70
    ID:11 -- Title:title -- Author:author -- Editor:editor -- YearOfRelease:2011 -- NumberOfUnits:7 -- ISBN:54
    ID:12 -- Title:hhh -- Author:hhh -- Editor:hh -- YearOfRelease:2004 -- NumberOfUnits:2 -- ISBN:77
```

For example, the passed value of isbn is 33 and the function is supposed to change the NumberOfUnits from 3 to 666 but it doesn't. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The data you write to the file is exactly the same as the data you just read from the file.  All of your `wordListX`'s are independent variables, changing them has absolutely no effect on `content`.

Comment: You shouldn't open a file to write while you already have it open for reading.

Comment: Usually you want to open the file, get the data inside and close it. Then process that data or do whatever. Finally open the fil again for writing, write to it and close it.

Comment: Please, how can I fix that Jason?

Comment: Even after doing what you said Daviid, the problem persists.

Comment: There's a lot wrong here. Besides writing to a file that is currently open, you are also assuming that doing `var1 = var2` and then `var2='new value'` will cause `var1` to update as well. This needs a full rewrite.

Comment: I'm rewriting it JNevill, hopefully, it'll work and I'll post it as an answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments there a couple of bigger issues with your code. First, the writing to a file that is already open; an issue that can be easily corrected with unindenting code. Second, the bigger issue is your assumption around how variables work. This second issue is more difficult to solve.

Here's a rewrite of your code, breaking up the functions into three operations:

1. A function for opening the file and turning the contents into a list of dictionaries object. This will make working with this data much easier for any other functionality you want to build in.
2. A function specifically to decrement a specific ISBN in this new books object. Separating this out to a single function helps compartmentalize the code and allows you to decrement more ISBN's while you have the books file open inside this object if you wish. This function is still spitting out `666` but that could be changed to `books[idx]['ISBN'] = str(int(books[idx]['ISBN']) - 1)` or what-have-you
3. A function to write the new books object out to a file in the same format from which it was read.

---

```
def getBooks(file):
    """
    The function `getBooks` reads a file, splits its content into lines, and then splits each line into
    key-value pairs to create a list of dictionaries representing books.
    
    :param file: The `file` parameter is the name or path of the file that contains the book information
    :return: a list of dictionaries, where each dictionary represents a book with key-value pairs for
    its attributes.
    """
    #open the file
    with open(file, 'r') as booksFile:
        content = booksFile.read().splitlines()
    
    #split each line to a list
    lines=[line.split(' -- ') for line in content]
    
    #turn entries in each line into a key:val pair for a dictionary
    books=[dict(entry.split(':') for entry in line) for line in lines]
    
    return books

def decrementBookUnits(books,isbn):   
    """
    The function `decrementBookUnits` takes a list of books and an ISBN number, and updates the ISBN of
    the book with the given ISBN number to '666'.
    
    :param books: A list of dictionaries representing books. Each dictionary contains information about
    a book, including its ISBN
    :param isbn: The `isbn` parameter is the ISBN (International Standard Book Number) of the book that
    you want to decrement the units for
    :return: the updated list of books after decrementing the units of a book with the given ISBN.
    """
    #iterate through the books list 
    for idx, entry in enumerate(books):
        #check if this entry has our isbn
        if entry['ISBN'] == str(isbn):
            #update the books entry's ISBN by updating the 
            # actual `books` object directly using the idx
            books[idx]['ISBN'] = '666'  

            #or actually decrement:
            #books[idx]['ISBN'] = str(int(books[idx]['ISBN']) - 1)
    return books

def writeBooks(books, file):
    """
    The function `writeBooks` takes a list of books and a file name as input, opens the file, iterates
    through the books, and writes each book entry to the file in a specific format.
    
    :param books: The "books" parameter is a list of dictionaries. Each dictionary represents a book and
    contains key-value pairs for different attributes of the book, such as title, author, genre, etc
    :param file: The `file` parameter is the name or path of the file where the books will be written
    """
    #Open file, iterate entries, and write back out
    with open(file, 'w') as booksFile:
        for entry in books:
            booksFile.writelines(' -- '.join(['='.join([k,v]) for k,v in entry.items()]) + '\n')

#get the contents of the book an object
# defined by the function
books=getBooks('books.txt')

#see what this looks like
print(books) 

#decrement books with an ISBN of 33
books=decrementBookUnits(books,33)

#write our books object back out to a file
# using a new file so this can be run over 
# and over again.
writeBooks(books,'books2.txt')
```

Answer (score 0):

how about update the lines that matches the given variable, write out to a different txt file

```
def decrementBookUnits(isbn):
    updated_lines = []
    with open('books.txt', 'r') as booksFile:
        content = booksFile.readlines()
    for line in content:
        if str(isbn) in line.lower():
            parts = line.split(' -- ')
            quantity_part = parts[5].split(':')
            quantity_part[1] = quantity_part[1].replace('3', '666')
            parts[5] = ':'.join(quantity_part)
            line = ' -- '.join(parts)
            updated_lines.append(line)
    with open('books2.txt', 'w') as booksFile2:
        booksFile2.writelines(updated_lines)
decrementBookUnits(33)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer nisakova, however, it is compulsory that I must work with a single file.